# weighting scheme of gstat for fitting models to variograms

Tags: r, variogram, gstat

I use R and the gstat package to construct variograms of temperature, and I would like to ask If anyone knows what weighting scheme does the gstat package use to fit a model to the sample variogram?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the `fit.method` chosen in the function `fit.variogram`. If you use:

- `fit.method = 0`, no fit
- `fit.method = 1`, weights are equal to *N<sub>j</sub>*
- `fit.method = 2`, weights are equal to *N<sub>j</sub> / {γ(h<sub>j</sub>)}<sup>2</sup>*
- `fit.method = 5`, REML (restricted maximum likelyhood)
- `fit.method = 6`, no weights (OLS = Ordinary Least Squares)
- `fit.method = 7`, *N<sub>j</sub> / h<sub>j</sub><sup>2</sup>*

Please see this:

- *Table 4.2: values for fit* in the [Gstat user's manual](http://www.gstat.org/gstat.pdf)
- *Details* section in the `fit.variogram` documentation